# Transfer files without LFTP hanging

Tags: ftp, lftp

I want to transfer a file using LFTP.

```
Connection Type: Passive connection Implicit SSL
Protocol: FTPS
```

Steps followed by me:

```
-bash-4.1$ set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
-bash-4.1$ set ftps:initial-prot
-bash-4.1$ set ftp:ssl-force true
-bash-4.1$ set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
-bash-4.1$ set ssl:verify-certificate off
-bash-4.1$ lftp
lftp :~> open ftps.host.com
lftp ftps.host.com:~> user u001
Password:
lftp u001@ftps.host.com:~> pwd
ftp://u001@ftps.host.com
lftp u001@ftps.host.com:~> ls
Interrupt
lftp u001@ftps.host.com:~> cd folderName
Interrupt
lftp u001@ftps.host.com:~> ls -ltr
`ls -ltr' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

Telnet is connecting & working but LFTP seems to hang. Can anybody please provide a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

lftp seems to be unable to connect to the server. You can use `debug` command to enable verbose messages and see what happens in detail. One of possible reasons is an incorrect port number to connect to. You can specify a port number explicitly by `-p NNN` option to `open` command, or just use `open ftp://u001@ftps.host.com:NNN` where NNN is the port number.

BTW, the `set` commands should be given *inside* lftp.